# Get random values from array on PHP using foreach and array_slice?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, slice

How can I randomize the results on this code ?

I have an array with more than four items on it, but I will like to get four of them only but not in order, how do I suppose to do that ? It can be done using `foreach(array_slice` ??

```
$i = 0;
foreach(array_slice($items_array,0,4) as $item) {
$output .= 'Item ID:'.$item['id'];
$i++;
}
```

**My array**

```
a:6:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"title";s:17:"Spedition";s:2:"id";s:11:"ZCXbgH1JDt4";s:3:"url";s:40:"embed/ZCXbgH1JDt4";s:5:"image";s:38:"transport";}i:1;a:4:{s:5:"title";s:77:"DC......
```

Comment: My Array doesnot looks like and array.

Comment: @subirkumarsao That is how ` array( 'url' => $url, 'idr' => $id, 'title' => $title )` is saved on the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved

```
$item = array_rand($items_array, 4); //get only four at random
$i=0;
while($i<=3) { // instead of 4 you set it at 3 because the counter starts at 0
$output = 'Item ID:'.$items_array[$item[$i]]['id'];             
$i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$output = array_rand($items_array, 4);
```

[`array_rand()`](http://php.net/array_rand)

Comment: Do you mean replace the whole foreach thing with that ?, can you elaborate a bit more ?

Answer (score 0):

Perfect Way for Get Random Value From Array

```
$numbers = range(1, 20);

shuffle($numbers); //this function will shuffle the array value

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo "$number ";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A better and easy solution would be using [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

```
$array          =  array("foo", "bar", "hallo", "world");
$rand_keys  =  array_rand($array,1);
echo $array[$rand_keys];
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it for you.

```
$i = 0;
foreach(array_rand($items_array, 4) as $item) {
  $output .= 'Item ID:'.$item['id'];
  $i++;
}
```